# VBScript GetObject WINNT properties

Tags: vbscript

I recently created a script for checking running services using the GetObject("WinNT://" & computer) method.  It uses a .filter method to only get "Service" items.  I have used similar scripts for querying other items from a computer.  However, I can't seem to find a list of everything that I should be able to query from a computer using this connection (prior to the filter)

Would someone be able to point me in the correct direction for finding out all of the possible properties I can access when using this type of connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the following section in MSDN:
[ADSI Objects of WinNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa772211.aspx)

It describes the available objects and their methods and properties.